# How to remove block comment before and after attribute value?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I create simple SSR-page with Next.js. Code of page:

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'

function Index({ stars }) {
    return <div>Welcome to {stars}!</div>
}

Index.getInitialProps = async ({ req }) => {
    const res = await fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/zeit/next.js');
    const json = await res.json()
    return { stars: json.stargazers_count }
};

export default Index
```

How to remove block comment before and after attribute value?

```
<div>Welcome to <!-- -->43671<!-- -->!</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every attribute should has it's own block.
**Fisrt solution**
You can put attribute to any tag (`<span>`, `<i>` and e.t.c.).

```
<div>Welcome to <span>{stars}</span>!</div>
```

**Second solution**
You can concat strings in parent tag.

```
<div>{'Welcome to '+stars+'!'}</div>
```